# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected - Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hopefully someone can give me some direction. My query:

```
SELECT
    wm.ID,
    wm.name,
    wm.meeting_type,
    m.start_date,
    wml.name as location
FROM
    webmaster.meeting wm inner join meetings m on wm.ID = m.Meeting_Code
    inner join webmaster.meeting_location on wml wm.locationID = wml.ID
WHERE
    Year(m.start_date) = Year(getDate())
ORDER BY
    m.start_date
```

When run, I get this error:

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'wm'.
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this from

```
inner join webmaster.meeting_location on wml wm.locationID = wml.ID

to 

inner join webmaster.meeting_location wml on wm.locationID = wml.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Comment: The value of a consistent code formatting style, is that these type of errors are easier to eyeball. i.e. put all the joins on their own line, and this would be easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    wm.ID,
    wm.name,
    wm.meeting_type,
    m.start_date,
    wml.name as location
FROM
    webmaster.meeting wm inner join meetings m on wm.ID = m.Meeting_Code
    inner join webmaster.meeting_location wml on wm.locationID = wml.ID
WHERE
    Year(m.start_date) = Year(getDate())
ORDER BY
    m.start_date
```